# int or NSInteger to NSUInteger for index

Tags: objective-c, nsuinteger

I'm trying to (in Xcode5) use the 'removeObjectAtIndex' for an 'MutableArray' which takes an NSUInteger  but the variable I'm using is an integer so I casted with (NSUInteger *) but I get a warning that says cast to 'NSUInteger *' (aka unsigned long *) from smaller integer type. I have not casted the variable 'second' in the code to keep the warning there but it is also an integer

```
-(void) moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger *)oldIndex toNewIndex:(NSUInteger *)newIndex{
    id *member = [self.array objectAtIndex:*oldIndex];
    [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:*oldIndex];
    if ((NSInteger)newIndex >=(self.array.count)) {
        newIndex--; //i casted newIndex because I got a warning about ordered comparison of NSUInteger with NSInteger (I'm not sure if this is best solution)
    }
    [self.array insertObject:member atIndex: *newIndex];
}

-(void)moveObjectInArray:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    [array moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger *) first toNewIndex:second];
}
```

Comment: Why the asterisks/pointers? Why not just pass these integers as parameters directly (and retrieve them directly)? You are less likely to confuse yourself, and you are not _doing_ anything with the pointers qua pointers (as far as I can see).

Comment: what you and @Chuck said regarding pointers and asterisk were totally on point. I made the suggestions everyone here said and that resolved the issues. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of pointers is all wonky. `id*` should just be `id` and `NSUInteger*` should just be `NSUInteger` — you don't want a pointer to a pointer to an object or a pointer to an integer here.

Answer (score 2):

What's problem for you of using just NSUInteger rather than NSUInteger* ?

```
-(void) moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)oldIndex toNewIndex:(NSUInteger)newIndex{
    id member = [self.array objectAtIndex:oldIndex]; //Here is id, id* is wrong
    [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:oldIndex];
    newIndex = newIndex >= self.array.count ? : self.array.count - 1; // Here should be self.array.count - 1, not newIndex-1
    newIndex = MIN(_cloudListArray.count, newIndex);
    [self.array insertObject:member atIndex:newIndex];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the following statement

```
if ((NSInteger)newIndex >=(self.array.count))
```

you are typecasting pointer to NSInteger. It should be

```
if ((NSInteger)*newIndex >=(self.array.count))
```

Still, you should be careful with typecasting and be wary of their consequences due to any signed/unsigned conversion or data loss.

Also, in this line

```
[array moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger *) first toNewIndex:second];
```

type of `first` should be `NSUInteger *` or of same size. Please note that long is 64-bit in 64-bit environment and typecasting as smaller pointer type to larger pointer type will yield undefined behaviour. Same applies to `second`. One solution is that use temporary variable and then copy back the result.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use a temporary variable? if i make NSUInteger *random = first the same warning applies and I cant use a variable of type id.